# if $g^k=e$ then $\chi(g)=\sum_j^n \zeta_k$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

> Let $G$ be a group. Let $g \in G$ and $g^k=e.$ Let $\chi$ be an
>    $n$-dimensional character of the group $G.$ Let $\zeta_k$ be  $k$-th root of unity.
>   Prove that $\chi(g)$  is equal  to sum of a $k$-th roots of unity.

My trying. Consider the cyclic subgroup $C_k \in G,$ Such  that $C_k=\{g^i| i<k\}.$
 Then any representation  $\rho$ of $C_k$ is equal to  prime sum of 1-dimensional representations $\rho_j$ of the group $C_k.$ Them number  is $n.$  and $\rho_j(g)=\zeta_k^r$ as $r|k.$

I'm not sure of the correctness of my proof

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $g^k = e$ then since the function $\rho: G \to GL_n(\mathbb C)$ that constitutes your representation is a homomorphism you have that $\rho(g^k) = \rho(g)^k = $ I, $ $thus in particular you know that all of the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ must be kth roots of unity (as for any $v \in \mathbb C^n$ you have that $\rho(g)^kv = v$, including its eigenvectors). But the character $\chi_\rho(g) = \text{Trace}(\rho(g))$ and the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues as you know from linear algebra. Thus it must be a sum of kth roots of unity.

Comment: I don't undenstand why "for any $v \in \mathbb C^n$ you have that $\rho(g)^kv = v$, including its eigenvectors " $\Rightarrow$ "all of the eigenvalues of $\rho(g)$ must be kth roots of unity." Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: $\rho(g)^k = \rho(g^k) = \rho(e) = I$ thus $\rho(g)^kv = v$ thus if v is an eigenvector of $\rho(g)$ then $\rho(g)^kv = \lambda^kv = v$ thus $\lambda$ is a kth root of unity. Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much!